# Strange shapes and lines while importing shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, import, australia

I am trying to add a Shapefile over the top of my map of Australia showing the extent of native grasslands.

However every time I add it all these extra lines and shapes appear over the top of the desired output (the grey irregular shapes within the map boundaries).

How do I get rid of these glitchy shapes over the top of everything?

[image: Strange grey shapes on top of image]

Comment: This may be caused by errors in the shapefile itself. Do you know the source of this shapefile, and are you able to verify with the shapefile's author that it's valid?

Comment: Thanks @StephenLead I was given the Shapefile a long time ago by my uni supervisor, I'm not sure where they got it. I didn't have this issue when I used the file previously, but the Shapefile has been on my USB for a couple of years, so I was thinking maybe it somehow got corrupted?

Comment: You could try testing it in an online shapefile viewer such as https://mapshaper.org/ - does it appear correctly there?

Comment: This looks like topographic errors, QGIS handles them more strictly than ArcGIS. Try and run `Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Check Validity...` to see if there are errors in the shapefile.

Comment: This may be due to differences in projections in the shapefile and the QGIS project.

Comment: Thanks for all your help everybody!! Issue resolved by going Vector > Geometry Tools > Check Validity as suggested by @JonasV

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @JonasV

> Issue resolved by going `Vector > Geometry Tools > Check Validity...`